# Open apps settings in ios react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking

Is there any way to open MYApp's app settings using React Native Linking.

I'm following [this](https://gist.github.com/deanlyoung/368e274945a6929e0ea77c4eca345560) for App-Prefs. But I'm not able to open any other settings than root settings page in IOS.

eg: `Linking.openURL('App-prefs:root=General&path=About');`

[image]

I am able to open app settings with [react-native-open-settings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-app-settings).

Is there any way to open app settings using Linking API provided by React Native.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me and opens settings of my application:

```
Linking.openURL('app-settings://');
```

Comment: You're right. Problem was with my app, app needs at least one permission to list the app under settings. I was trying to open it without any permissions. After that the code is working fine. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @Shubham You're welcome, and good point about having at least one capability.